# C++ Unary - Operator Overload Won't Compile

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am attempting to create an overloaded unary - operator but can't get the code to compile. A cut-down version of the code is as follows:-

```
class frag
{
    public:

        frag myfunc  (frag oper1,
                      frag oper2);
        frag myfunc2  (frag oper1,
                      frag oper2);

        friend frag operator + (frag &oper1,
                                frag &oper2);

        frag operator - ()
        {
            frag f;
            f.element = -element;
            return f;
        }

    private:

        int element;

};

frag myfunc (frag oper1, frag oper2)
{
    return oper1 + -oper2;
}

frag myfunc2 (frag oper1, frag oper2)
{
    return oper1 + oper2;
}

frag operator+ (frag &oper1, frag &oper2)
{
    frag innerfrag;
    innerfrag.element = oper1.element + oper2.element;
    return innerfrag;
}
```

The compiler reports...

```
/home/brian/Desktop/frag.hpp: In function ‘frag myfunc(frag, frag)’:
/home/brian/Desktop/frag.hpp:41: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘oper1 + oper2.frag::operator-()’
/home/brian/Desktop/frag.hpp:16: note: candidates are: frag operator+(frag&, frag&)
```

Could anyone suggest what I need to be doing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**const-correctness**

This has to be

```
 frag operator+ (const frag &oper1, const frag &oper2);
```

or else the operands can't be temporaries, such as the return value of `operator-`

And unary minus should rather be:

```
frag operator - () const;
```

since it shouldn't modify the operand.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have an `operator+` that can operate on temporaries. Temporaries cannot be passed as non-const reference.

Change the signature of your `operator+` to:

```
frag operator + (const frag &oper1, const frag &oper2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Though your question has already been answered reasonably well, I think it's worth mentioning another point about your code. Right now, you have the following declarations:

```
class frag
{
    public:

        frag myfunc  (frag oper1,
                      frag oper2);
        frag myfunc2  (frag oper1,
                      frag oper2);
```

... and you have the following functions:

```
frag myfunc (frag oper1, frag oper2)
{
    return oper1 + -oper2;
}

frag myfunc2 (frag oper1, frag oper2)
{
    return oper1 + oper2;
}
```

I'd guess that you intended these two functions to implement the member functions you declared in `frag` -- but they don't. Instead, you have two member functions that are declared by never defined, and these two are global functions that happen to have similar names. For them to *be* the member functions you declared, you need to change the declaration to something like:

```
frag frag::myfunc(frag oper1, frag oper2) { 
    return oper1 + -oper2;
}

frag frag::myfunc2(frag oper1, frag oper2) { 
    return oper1 + oper2;
}
```

On the other hand, these don't really make any sense that way either -- in particular, as member functions, they'll normally be invoked as something like: `a.myfunc(b,c);` They're both really written like global functions though -- as member functions, they'd normally take only one parameter, and use `this` as the first parameter:

```
frag frag::myfunc1(frag oper) { 
    return *this + -oper;
}
frag frag::myfunc2(frag oper) { 
    return *this + oper;
}
```

Of course, this may just be an accidental side effect from trying to reduce the original code to a minimum necessary for posting. If so, please feel free to disregard this whole "answer"....

Comment: I think you are right about it being a result of my creating a minimal criminal, as this doesn't appear in my substantive version, but thank you for mentioning it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has already been given (const arguments), but I'd like to mention that Visual C++ 9 (VS-2008) would indeed compile the above without warning.